# What is maximum guaranteed range of N-bit signed integer?

Tags: c++, standards, bit, theory, signed

Some background:

- Prior to C++20, the C++ Standard allowed any signed integer representation, and the minimum guaranteed range of N-bit signed integers was from `-(2^(N-1) - 1)` to `+2^(N-1) - 1`.
- C++20 standard *proposal (as mentioned by @Sneftel)* allowed the only representation with the guaranteed range from `-2^(N-1)` to `+2^(N-1) - 1`.
- As far as I understand the range of values min-max must be continuous.

I've tried to find any quotes for the maximum range of N-bit signed integer but found none.

So I wonder (in terms of C++):

1. Is it right to assume that maximum possible range of N-bit signed integer is limited from `-2^(N-1)` to `+2^(N-1)`? Could it be wider?
2. Could it be affected by underlying platform bit implementation - like "3-state-bit" or something like that?

Comment: Standard does not limit the *maximum* possible range. It just guarantees its minimum.

Comment: @Zefick that's...obvious I think and doesn't answer the question. Let me rephrase it: how could N-bit signed integer be wider then {-2^(N-1); +2^(N-1)}?

Comment: @Zefick it sounds like you're thinking of earlier versions of the language.

Comment: @UKMonkey expected by what? Let's have an example: I have INT_MAX = 2 ^ 42 and 32-bit int. Is it conforming standard? If it is - how is it possible?

Comment: "Is it conforming standard?" Pre-C++20 yes. "if it is - how is it possible?"  It probably isn't; but the standard didn't care.

Comment: @UKMonkey Now you understand! I want to turn this "probably" to "certainly" with your answers =)

Comment: No - I still don't understand.  My current comparison of your question is  "Does a building code permit anti-gravity machines in an industrial environment?  Yes.  Is it possible?  Probably not."   Maybe you have another question; "is it possible now?"  In which case the question isn't really about the standard.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yes. But anti-gravity machines existence possibility could be questionable. Platform with INT_MAX = 2 ^ 42  and 32-bit int existence (in terms of C++) possibility must be known for sure.

Comment: So your question is infact "can an N bit integer hold more than 2^N range" - and nothing to do with c++?  I'm not saying it's a bad question - at all - it's just a very confusing one as it stands

Comment: @UKMonkey it is more complex but yes. If you want to continue discussion let's move to chat then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++2a, while projected to become the C++20 standard, is not there yet.

Aside from that, while the current draft enforces [two's-complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for signed integers, the current Standard (C++17) and all precursors do *restrict choice*:
Specifically, the other options offered are [signed magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation_(SMR)) and [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement). Both feature **negative zero**.

There is information on the range of N-bit signed integers. Specifically, that not all of those N<sub>1</sub> bits of the object-representation need be part of the N<sub>2</sub> bits of the value-representation, with [the exception of the narrow character types](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#7). So, the value-representation's N-bit width might be smaller. Considering the [pigeonhole-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it is no surprise it cannot be bigger.

The assumption that bits are binary is deeply embedded in the language, just like it pervades many other programming-languages. Changing that would be a major project.

Answer (score 3):

There is not currently a final C++20 standard. The *proposal* you're likely thinking of is P1236, and it says:

> The range of representable values for a signed integer type is -2^(N-1) to 2^(N-1)-1 (inclusive), where N is called the range exponent of the type.

That's both a maximum and a minimum. Because the proposal requires two's complement for signed integers, there's no opportunity for variation. Trivially, N bits cannot be used to represent more than 2^N distinct values (by the pigeonhole principle), so that range is as big as things can get, even if it were specified only as a minimum range.

As for three-state bits, those don't work with the language.

Comment: So have I right to assume that prior to C++20 the maximum must be "from -2^(N-1) to +2^(N-1)"? And in C++20 proposal it changes to "from -2^(N-1) to +2^(N-1)-1"?

Comment: That N (the "range exponent") didn't exist as a concept before C++20, so that's not really an answerable question. But in this universe, there cannot be an N-bit integer type which can represent any value in the inclusive range -2^(N-1) to +2^(N-1).

Comment: That's an answer I think. Term "range exponent" did not exist but rule for the range for N-bit signed integer from -(2^(N-1) - 1) to +2^(N-1) - 1 did, didn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderG. -- currently the requirements have values that are -2^(N-1)+1 to +2^(N-1)-1. So for a 16-bit value, the range is -32767..+32767. That range has one value less than the full range that N bits could represent. That allows for ones-complement, twos-complement, and sign-magnitude representations, among others (those three are the most common).